# Using Linq in .NET Handlers

Tags: linq, ashx

I have a Handler and I am trying to perform LINQ operations. However I cannot. Is it possible to do this in .ASHX files?

```
using (UserDataContext userDataContext = new UserDataContext)
{
    User user = userDataContext.Users.Single -- Does not show up as an option in intellisense.
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added import?

```
using System.Linq;
```